# How to make Media Foundation H.264 decoder work?

Tags: h.264, ms-media-foundation, transport-stream

For some reason I'm not able to decode H.264.
The input/output configuration went well, just like input/output buffer creation.

I'm manually feeding the decoder with the H.264 demuxed from a live stream. Therefore, I use MFVideoFormat_H264_ES as media subtype. The decoding is very slow and the decoded frames are complete garbage. Other decoders are decoding the same stream properly.

Weird thing is that once ProcessInput() returns MF_E_NOTACCEPTING, the following ProcessOutput() returns MF_E_TRANSFORM_NEED_MORE_INPUT. According to MSDN, this should never happen.

Can anybody provide some concrete info on how to do it? (assuming that MF H.264 is functional, which I seriously doubt).

I'm willing to provide extra information, but I don't know what somebody might need in order to help.

Edit:
When exactly should I reset the number of bytes in input buffer to zero?
Btw, I'm resetting the output buffer when ProcessOutput() delivers something (garbage).

Edit2:
Without resetting the current buffer size on input buffer to 0, I managed to get some semi valid output. By semi valid I mean that on every successful ProcessOutput() I receive an YUV image where current image contains a few decoded macro blocks more than the previous frame. The rest of the frame is black. Because I do not reset the size, this stops after a while. So, I guess there is a problem in resetting the buffer size and I guess I should get some notification when the whole frame is done (or not).

Edit3:
While creating input buffer, GetInputStreamInfo() returns 4096 as input buffer size. Alignment 0. However, 4k is not enough. Increasing to 4MB helps in decompressing frame fragment by frame fragment. Still have to figure out if there is a way to tell when is the entire frame decoded.

Comment: How do you call SetInputType and SetOutputType of the decoder? Have you sent MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING and MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM messages before the first call to ProcessInput?

Comment: You shouldn't reset neither the input nor the output buffer. Quote from MSDN: "If the caller allocates the media sample, the media sample must contain a buffer that is large enough to hold the output data. To find the buffer requirements, call GetOutputStreamInfo. The MFT writes the output data to the start of the buffer, overwriting any data that already exists in the buffer." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms704014(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, both messages were successfully sent, MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_BEGIN_STREAMING and MFT_MESSAGE_NOTIFY_START_OF_STREAM . SetInputType & SetOutputType went well. While decoding I received a MF_E_TRANSFORM_STREAM_CHANGE and handled it successfully. When it comes to buffer overwriting, things doesn't really work as MSDN describes. On some decoders I had to reset buffer length to 0 once the ProcessOutput() delivered something.

Comment: Just an update, if I do not reset the output buffer to zero after successful ProcesOutput() I get error (E_FAIL), so that has to stay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating input buffer, GetInputStreamInfo() returns 4096 as buffer size, which is too small.
Setting input buffer to 4MB solved the problem. The buffer can probably be smaller... still have to test that.

Comment: Still, MF produces garbage instead of correct frames as other decoders. It's pretty much useless after all.